# How to apply css only to those elements, which in the block

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to apply the file of style only to those elements, which in the block.
examples:

```
<body>
<p>greem green zero</p>
<span> hello </span>
<div id="main">
...more tags...
</div>
<ul><li>1233</li></ul>
...
</body>
```

it is necessary to apply file.css only to those tags and all to that in the ***div:id block = "main"***.
but thus not to touch everything that outside of this block, is a lot of elements with the files styles there

maybe using iframe?

Comment: No don't use an iframe for that, that is for sure!

Comment: Where's your CSS and what's JavaScript got to do with this?

Comment: css files are designed to be applied to a page, but you can make your code specific to the block

Comment: this is the structure #main > .child > .child etc.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? No need for iframe, just use CSS selectors.

http://jsfiddle.net/terda12/ryrbf8qs/

```
body p {
    color: green;
}

#main {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of three options for this:

- Using an `<iframe/>`. I wouldn't.
- Manually processing the CSS with JavaScript. Heavy stuff! But maybe one of the existing libraries / frameworks can do that.
- Making sure that the selectors of the rules in `file.css` are specific enough, like i.e. `#main p {...}` instead of `p {...}`.

The selectors is the best solution in most cases.

Comment: I insert the text created in ckedit to it the contents.css is necessary what beautifully to display everything. But this file violates all page, and not just that text from the editor.

Comment: @Yur4k What is "ckedit"? What are you talking about? Why is "ckedit" relevant? Or do you mean "ckeditor"?

Comment: yes, I was mistaken, ckeditor. it is necessary for its display to connect contents.css but when I connect it all site changes, and to change all styles in the site.

Comment: I will change my styles very long. maybe it is possible to solve differently

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<p>greem green zero</p>
<span> hello </span>
<div id="main">
    <div id="stuffInTheMain">kjsdhf ksklshdf lkd </div>
    <p id="iAmInMainTo">paragraph text</p>
</div>
<ul><li>1233</li></ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    color: red;
}
#main{
    color: blue;
}
```

View the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uksuumbh/